# Three-fiber get spotlight with a new position to point straight down

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

In three-fiber, I have a spotlight, but it is "pointing" at {[0,0,0]}.  I tried adjusting the `target` and the `lookAt` properties to {[0,0,0]}

```
<spotLight position={[0, 20, -20]} intensity={1.5} color="#fff" penumbra={0.5} castShadow={false} />
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')

As soon as I take away the target, it works, but its still pointing at [0,0,0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target` of `SpotLight` must be an object added to the scene.  https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/SpotLight.target

React-three-fiber implementation:

```
const spotlight = useMemo(() => new SpotLight('#fff'), []);


<group>
  <primitive
    object={spotlight}
    position={[0, 20, -20]}
    intensity={1.5}
    penumbra={0.5}
  />
  <primitive object={spotlight.target} position={[0, 0, 0]} />
</group>
```